# making a label as a url link in flex builder

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I need to make a label in flex as if you click on it you can open a specific URL let us say Google.

Any ideas?

regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is sample:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.net.navigateToURL;
        protected function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.google.com");
            navigateToURL(urlReq, "_self");
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Label x="110" y="149" text="Open Google" click="clickHandler(event)"/>
```